# IntelliJ add persistance support

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I want to add hibernate support to my project using IntelliJ IDE, like described in this page;

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/enabling-hibernate-support.html

But I cant see the "Hibernate" from the list of facets available for this module, I added hibernate core to my POM file but didn't help.

Any Ideas how can I add add this facet to my module?

*Note: the reason I need it because I want it to automatically create entity classes from my data source*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid, I restarted IDE and and problem solved..Probably it didn't pick up hibernate support or something.

Answer (score 1):

As Sergey Chernetsky wrote in the page you're linking to:

> Most probably, you are using the IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. In this edition, neither Hibernate nor Web development is supported. See [IntelliJ IDEA Editions Comparison](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Is this the case?

Comment: No I use ultimate edition, what has to be in my project so Intellij should suggest hibernate? I didnt define datasource yet maybe thats it?

Comment: Did you activate the "Hibernate Support" plugin?